# List in Javascript that adds and displays all items

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a list in Javascript that has a submit button. Once an item is entered I would like it to display under the previously inputted item. So far the item I put in replaces the one before it. Any directions greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show some code for what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing which you are looking for ->

[OPEN for DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gmyag/)

HTML Code:

```
First name:
<input type="text" id="firstname">
<br>
<p>Your first name is: <b id='boldStuff2'></b> 
</p>
<p>Other people's names:</p>
<ol id="demo"></ol>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Submit' />
```

and JS:

```
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

function changeText2() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = firstname;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
    list.appendChild(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.appendChild()` should fix your problem. In addition, thanks to the `submit` event, you can either click on the submit button or press ENTER.

```js
ul = document.getElementById("ul");
form = document.getElementById("form");
div = document.createElement("div");
form.elements.text.focus();

form.addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
  var textEl = this.elements.text;
  ul.appendChild(makeLI(textEl.value));
  textEl.value = "";
  ev.preventDefault();
});

function makeLI (content) {
  div.innerHTML = "<ul><li>" + content + "</li></ul>";
  return div.firstChild.firstChild;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </p>
</form>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as it is. Consider the following example:

```
<html>
<input id="name"></input>
<label id="nameDisplay"></label>
<input id="place"></input>
<label id="placeDisplay"></label>
<button onclick="display()">Click</button>
</html>

<script>
function display(){
    name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    place= document.getElementById('place').value;
    document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('placeDisplay').innerHTML = place;
}
</script>
```

Here the 'innerHTML' is the strong weapon used for your question! This will erase the previous code and display the current value only.

Comment: I believe the OP wants the list to continue growing with each press. This only creates the first entry.

Comment: Oh.. Great! appendChild()  must be the best solution!